# Contracts in WCF .NET must be in shared dll?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, datacontract

I need to send data out-of-proc and both processes are running c# .net. I'm using WCF over tcp.ip. I define a service interface contract, and a data contract that I send from one proc to another. I have found that unless I made the service interface and the data contract common code shared in a dll between the two processes, it doesn't work. Is this the right way it works or am I missing something?

Initially, I tried to have each process host the service interface and data contracts. The data contract class looked the same with the only exception of namespace, and a using. WCF couldn't deserialize the data contract - it complained that it couldn't find the reference (in the using). Then I changed the code to have the contracts be in a shared dll.

Comment: It can work, however datacontracts are extremely specific.  Anything out of order, the wrong type, the wrong case etc will cause serialization to fail.  I suggest posting the code you've attempted to make that has failed